# dynamic div height is not working in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

pls chk this link 
[dynamic link height problem](http://www.wasiyat.com/step3.html)

now click on the text **i would like to give specific gifts**

the inner div generated is not rendering properly in ie8. rest its working properly in ie 7, firefox,safari etc etc.
This rendering is working perfectly in ie compatibility mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something that I aways do is to make IE8 behave like IE7 with this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

(place it above of your `<title>` tags)

Since you said that it works in IE7 this should not only fix your problem now, but any kind of problem with IE8 in the future.

Comment: This doesn't really fix his problem with the way IE8's rendering engine handles his page, it just tells IE8 to act like IE7... Also, I think you meant <title> not <tittle>